# Paypal MPL IOS not calling - (void)paymentSuccessWithKey

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hello everyone I am having a problem that is the paypal delegate -

```
(void)paymentSuccessWithKey:(NSString *)payKey andStatus:(PayPalPaymentStatus)paymentStatus {
```

is never called when the transaction is successful and over. Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [PayPal initializeWithAppID:kPayPalAPI
                 forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}


-(IBAction)payWithPayPal{

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[[PayPalPayment alloc] init] autorelease];
    payment.recipient = @"xxxx@mail.com";
    payment.paymentCurrency = @"EUR";
    payment.description =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test tetst %@",stest];
    payment.merchantName = @"Test product";

    //subtotal of all items, without tax and shipping
    payment.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:txtMontant.text];

    PayPalInvoiceItem *item = [[[PayPalInvoiceItem alloc] init] autorelease];
    item.totalPrice = payment.subTotal;
    item.name = @"Test";
    [payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems addObject:item];

    [[PayPal getPayPalInst] checkoutWithPayment:payment];

}
```

I have set the delegate like this `ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,PayPalPaymentDelegate>` . Is there anything i am missing ?

Comment: Are you using it in iOS 6

Comment: this method will not work in iOS 6 please cheack any other method

Comment: which method : - (void)paymentSuccessWithKey:(NSString *)payKey andStatus:(PayPalPaymentStatus)paymentStatus { ?

Comment: yes dude :) this method

Comment: humm hi there thanks weird but i am testing on ios 6.1.3 from the sample project "simple demo" there its calling the above method :(

Comment: Same issue i got in my previous project and searched alot then after i found that it is depricated. :( thats why i told you

Comment: can u mail the dummy project on my mail so i can check it :)

Comment: I have downloaded it from here https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/blob/gh-pages/MPL/PayPalMPL_2-0-1-iPhone_DevelopersPackage.zip. Thanks :)

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/ 

Try this it may help you coz i have done it by same way

Comment: humm oki but i have to use MPL version Non-US developers, you can continue to use MPL for the time being.

Comment: hmm i will check that and let you you know about this

Comment: you think because i have implemented my own button its causing the problem ? i am checking and implementing the button provided in the demo.

Comment: the problem was the button i had to use the button provided. Its some sort of enabled when the initialization is completed.Thanks for your time & help @Divz

Comment: Great @veereef Thanks alot for updating me i have to check my previous code thanks :)

Comment: u r welcome. btw the transaction id NSString* transactionId = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:payKey];
    NSLog(@"transactionId: %@", transactionId); is it the real transaction id or we have to use other means to get it?

Comment: i think here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/ this is how we can get the details .. ..

Answer (score 0):

If u want to get paykey

Using this method:

```
(void)paymentSuccessWithKey:(NSString *)payKey andStatus:(PayPalPaymentStatus)paymentStatus
```

With your own custom button.Try this below code:

```
 _your_custom_button = [[PayPal getPayPalInst]getPayButtonWithTarget:self
                       andAction:@selector(paywithpaypal)
                       andButtonType:BUTTON_278x43
                       andButtonText:BUTTON_TEXT_PAY];
```

And do payment in `paywithpaypal` method.